# On publishing infopath 2010 form loses control properties - dropdown control data binding setting

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am try to created a cascade dropdown using infopath 2010 in sharepoint 2010 list. On publishing infopath form i lost data binding setting and it just resets to default "Enter choices manually". It works perfectly only if i dont publish it (preview mode). I even recreated infopath form many times but of no use. It works perfectly on some other site but not on where i want to.
[note: Dropdown are lookup columns]

Comment: You might also try here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check your form settings at dropdown box properties > Browser forms > Post back settings, make sure its set to Always.